# How do I handle exceptions in BeautifulSoup if the element I'm looking for is not found?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am making an http request to a website and parse its content to find some attribute values. What I need to know is how do I handle exceptions if code returns `[]`, `None` or nothing at all.

What I have tried:

```
import requests
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_url():

    s = requests.Session()

    retries = Retry(total=5,
                    backoff_factor=10
                    status_forcelist=[ 500, 502, 503, 504 ])

    s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

    r = s.get('http://httpstat.us/500')

def find_data():

    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
    try:
        id = soup.find('a', class_="class").get('id')
    except:
        print('id not found')
        get_url()
```

Basically if the `id` is not to find I want to make that GET request again and try to find it.

Comment: You probably are looking for a `for` or `while` loop. Generally, if you try to `get` again, it won't return anything different, so be aware of that if you put this into a loop, you could end up with an infinite loop.

Comment: @SumnerEvans agreed, OP is clearly just looking for a way to handle missing elements in his code.

Comment: Also, is this the complete code? Where does `r` come from? See: [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the "look before you leap" ([`LBYL`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-lbyl)) principle and check the result of `find()` - it would return `None` if an element was not found. You can then put the thing into a loop and exit when you have a value, also safeguarding yourself with a loop counter limit:

```
RETRIES = 10

id = None
session = requests.Session()

for attempt in range(1, RETRIES + 1):
    response = session.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

    element = soup.find('a', class_="class", id=True)
    if element is None:
        print("Attempt {attempt}. Element not found".format(attempt=attempt))
        continue
    else:
        id = element["id"]
        break

print(id)
```

Couple notes:

- `id=True` was set to find only elements with the `id` element present. You could also do an equivalent with a [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `soup.select_one("a.class[id]")`
- `Session()` helps to improve performance when issuing requests to the same host multiple times. See more at [Session Objects](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)

Comment: But what if I want the request to be in a separate `def` to better handle errors? See my updated code.

Answer (score -1):

If all you want to do is make that same request a second time, you could do something like this:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def find_data(url):
    found_data = False
    while not found_data:
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        try:
            id = soup.find('a', class_="class").get('id')
            found_data = True
        except:
            pass
```

This puts you at risk of an infinite loop if the data really aren't there. You can do this to avoid that infinite loop:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def find_data(url, attempts_before_fail=3):
    found_data = False
    while not found_data:
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
        try:
            id = soup.find('a', class_="class").get('id')
            found_data = True
        except:
            attempts_before_fail -= 1
            if attempts_before_fail == 0:
                raise ValueError("couldn't find data after all.")
```

Comment: But what if I want the request to be in a separate `def` to better handle errors? See my updated code.